# Google Analytics on a single page without hashes

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, single-page-application

I operate a website that consists of a single page.
The navigation bar has 5-6 sections (like references, contact, T&C), and a click on any of them scrolls down to the appropriate section (div). They are not loaded dynamicly.

Due to the used JS (smooth scrolling etc.), the URL hash does NOT change while scrolling or link-clicking. Is there any way to track the users navigation in google analytics?

I have tested several answers here on SO, but they all require the url hash to change.

Comment: I would say you might want to post this on google forums for analytics.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from:[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications)

Read below, and depending on how your site is setup, you could use scroll triggered ajax calls to send the below "pageview" call, or something like that. hope this helps.

**Single Page Application Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)**

This guide describes how to use analytics.js to track pages on sites whose content is loaded dynamically without traditional full page loads.

The analytics.js snippet is part of Universal Analytics. If you're using Classic Analytics (ga.js) visit the Upgrade Center to learn how to migrate your property to analytics.js.
Overview

A Single Page Application (SPA) is a web application or website that loads all of the resources required to navigate throughout the site on the first page load. As the user clicks links and interacts with the page, subsequent content is loaded dynamically. The application will often update the URL in the address bar to emulate traditional page navigation, but another full page request is never made.

The default analytics.js snippet code works well with traditional websites because the snippet code is run every single time the users load a new page. However, for a single page application where you're loading new page content dynamically rather than as full page loads, the analytics.js snippet code only runs once. This means subsequent (virtual) pageviews must be tracked manually as new content is loaded.

Tracking virtual pageviews

To track dynamically loaded content as distinct pageviews you can send a pageview hit to Google Analytics and specify the Document Path by setting the page field.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/new-page');
```

The page field represents the path portion of a URL and should begin with a slash. Usually the page value is the same as the path portion of the URL shown in the browser's address bar, but it doesn't have to be. Since websites that load content dynamically often only update the hash portion of the URL as the user navigates, several different URL paths may point to the same resource. In these cases, it's usually best to choose a canonical URL and only ever send that page value to Google Analytics.

For example, consider a website whose "About Us" page can be reached via any of the following URLs:

```
/about.html
/#about.html
/home.html#about.html
```

To avoid duplication in your reports, it's best to track all of these pageviews as      /about.html.

Setting page data for multiple hits

Specifying a page value in a pageview hit will send that page value to Google Analytics for that hit only; it will not update the page value stored on the tracker object itself. This can be problematic if you send other hits (e.g. events or social hits) and don't explicitly include the current page value. In such cases, Google Analytics will associate those hits with whatever URL was present at the time of the initial page load.

To avoid this issue, it's usually best to update the tracker object with any new page information prior to sending hits. This will ensure that all hits are associated with the correct page data.

To update the tracker object, use the set method:

ga('set', 'page', '/new-page');
If you want to update more than just the page field, you can pass an object of key/value pairs to the set method.

```
ga('set', {page: '/new-page', title: 'New Page'
```

});
Once the tracker has been updated with the proper data for the new page, you can send a hit without overriding page related parameters. For example:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```